# how to preserve the single quotes in xml attribute while insertion in oracle 11g

Tags: xml, oracle11gr2

I am inserting the xml files in oracle database.My input xml files has attributes which use single quotes to surround the value.It should not be changed.But after insertion i could see inserted xml files uses double quotes to surround the attribute values.Can anyone please help me on this to store the xml file as it is?

Iam inserting as below in oracle

```
<address inferred-city='LAS CRUCES' inferred-country='USA' inferred-county='DONA ANA' inferred-phone-area-code='505' inferred-state='NM' lat='32.322399' lma='MT352974' lon='-106.804123' majorcity='LAS CRUCES' msa='29740: METROPOLITAN STATISTICAL AREA' state='NM'>
```

But the output is

```
<address inferred-city="LAS CRUCES" inferred-country="USA" inferred-county="DONA ANA" inferred-phone-area-code="505" inferred-state="NM" lat="32.322399" lma="MT352974" lon="-106.804123" majorcity="LAS CRUCES" msa="29740: METROPOLITAN STATISTICAL AREA" state="NM">
```

Comment: Why does it matter? The two serializations represent exactly the same XML. If you care about features like this that are below the XML level then you're dealing with text, not XML, and you should store the data as text.

Comment: Yes it does matter.I need the way how to preserve the single quotes during the insertion of xml as binary type.

Comment: Then you'll have to store it as a LOB rather than in structured form.

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in a CLOB type column. This will preserve all formatting you need.